# Por que mi clase en JS me dice undefined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Hola estoy aprendiendo a programar en JS y pues estoy creando una clase pero esta me dice que no esta definida quisiera saber por que pasa esto llevo rato viendo el codigo pero no veo nada mal.

```js
class celulares {
            constructor(color, peso, resPantalla, resCamara, ram) {
                this.color = color;
                this.peso = peso;
                this.resPantalla = resPantalla;
                this.resCamara = resCamara;
                this.ram = ram;
                this.info = `El celular es de color ${this.color}, pesa ${this.peso} gramos, tiene una resolucion de pantalla de ${this.resPantalla}, la camara tiene una resolucion de ${this.resCamara} mega-pixeles y tiene ${this.ram}gb de memoria Ram`;
        } 

    }   const cel1 = new celulares("rojo", 200, 1280, 40, 4);
        document.write(celulares.info);
```

Comment: Creo que porque estas llamando a la clase celulares, y abajo la estas instanciando como cel1, debes llamarlo con el nombre que instancias la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy simple la solución. Solamente hay que llamar a la instancia de la clase que creaste.

En este caso solo basta con hacer `document.write(cel1.info)`, ya que `cel1` es el nombre de la instancia e `info` la propiedad.

```js
class celulares {
            constructor(color, peso, resPantalla, resCamara, ram) {
                this.color = color;
                this.peso = peso;
                this.resPantalla = resPantalla;
                this.resCamara = resCamara;
                this.ram = ram;
                this.info = `El celular es de color ${this.color}, pesa ${this.peso} gramos, tiene una resolucion de pantalla de ${this.resPantalla}, la camara tiene una resolucion de ${this.resCamara} mega-pixeles y tiene ${this.ram}gb de memoria Ram`;
        } 

    }   const cel1 = new celulares("rojo", 200, 1280, 40, 4);
        document.write(cel1.info);
```

Esto es así porque `celulares` no es un objeto. Más bien es una "clase" que sirve para construir un objeto.

Te recomiendo que revises la definición de [clases](https://www.masqueteclas.com/articulo/el-concepto-de-clase/) en la programación orientada a objetos.